# Wrong use of onload()?

Tags: java, ajax

[image]is this wrong because i get loadData as undefined?

```
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">               
  function loadData() {
    var name  = $("#surname").val();        
    $.ajax({     
      url: 'checkdata.php',                      
      type: 'POST',       
      data: { 'surname' : surname }        
    });
    alert(data);
   //return false;
 </script>
 </head>
<body onload="loadData()">
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="php/save-edit.php" >
```

i have a form where i want to extract data from a db and display it in the form fields on form load

Comment: I am not sure what you want to ask here. But as per code the DB call u can do in java then come to jsp. it will reduce the jsp build time.

Comment: am i using the onload the correct way? that is my question :) because why am i getting loadData is undefined?

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` on the end of your `loadData`, hence `loadData` not being created and it being undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understand you are using code code.Please try below code.
Just change `<body onload="loadData()">` to `<body onload="javascript:loadData();">` and try. it may help.

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">               
  function loadData() {
    var name  = $("#surname").val();        
    $.ajax({     
      url: 'checkdata.php',                      
      type: 'POST',       
      data: { 'surname' : name }        
    });
    alert(data);
   //return false;
 }
 </script>
 </head>
<body onload="javascript:loadData();">
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="php/save-edit.php" >
```

Comment: i think i have a sytax error somewhere?? please see pic in OP

Comment: data: { 'surname' : surname }  to  data: { 'surname' : name} and we miss '}' for the function.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be happened because of running the onload event before creating the HTML object.

It would be better if you use like as follow :

```
$( document ).ready(function() { your function });
```

Hope this help.